# Is it possible in the android plugin (gradle) to specify the path to buildTools and platforms folders

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

In my android-sdk folder i have some dirs (tools, build-tools, platforms, etc...)

Can i move folders (for example tools or build-tools) to another place and after in gradle project plugin to specify the path to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after investigation answer is no